# Prevent a query from returning the same row to different threads

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API service that matches users according to some conditions.

A user must not get more than one match in a specified interval.

To create a match I'm using an SQL query (the database is SQL Server):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
FROM table_name
WHERE last_match >= DATEADD(hour, -3, GETDATE()) and **some_other_conditions** 
ORDER BY last_match desc;
```

As there are multiple calls to this service **some_other_conditions** might be identical for different users and the only thing that will differentiate the result is the last_match column.

The problem is that while user A is making this call last_match column is not updated yet and so other users might get the same match.

How can I avoid or solve this issue?

Comment: You create a `BlockingCollection<Action>` or any thread safe collection <Action>, queue the queries and then process the collection with a dedicated (service) thread or a timer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can do that in SQL Server, although database is definitely not the best place to implement such things. The query needs to be tweaked a bit, by adding several hints, such as:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table_name with (xlock, holdlock, rowlock, readpast)
WHERE last_match >= DATEADD(hour, -3, GETDATE()) and **some_other_conditions** 
ORDER BY last_match desc;
```

The first 3 hints ensure that the row selected by one connection will remain inaccessible to others until its transaction is committed. The `readpast` hint allows the query to skip rows locked by other transactions, and keep going further, looking for a suitable match, without waiting for the locks to be released.

A couple of caveats that you need to keep in mind:

1. The entire unit of work has to be performed within a single client-side transaction, using the same database connection. Make sure that you do not have more than 1 connection per application thread, and that connections are not shared between threads;
2. The `readpast` hint allows to skip row-level locks, but it doesn't skip page locks. You will have to somehow make sure that no page locks, let alone partition or table locks, would be placed on this table.
3. If you have any amount of simultaneous connections worth mentioning, you can easily exhaust the lock buffer, which is not configurable in SQL Server. Thankfully, Database Engine can grow it dynamically when necessary, but you still can run into unexpected situations when excessive lock contention will result in a noticeable performance drop.
4. If your database has RCSI enabled, you will need to add the `readcommittedlock` hint to your query. Without it, locks wouldn't mean anything, as other connections will be able to read "previous versions" of selected matches (which, in this case, would have the same data as the row selected by another thread).

If you are going to pursue this approach, make sure to carry out a full-scale stress test before rolling it into production.